# INDEX MATCH with multiple criteria from pivot table

Tags: excel

OK, I am trying to reference a cell in a pivot table based on multiple criteria. I thought I had it figured out but now I am getting a #Ref! error.

Here is my current formula:

```
=INDEX(MP_Val_Table[Instrument Line],MATCH($B8,MP_Val_Table[Assay],0),MATCH($B10,MP_Val_Table[Mobile Phase],0))
```

[image: MP_VAL_Table]

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Comment: INDEX takes a range of cells followed by a row number and column number to return in that range. Your match criteria would appear to both be returning row numbers that match your $B8 and $B10 values, since your table is 50 rows by 8 columns your last match result could return a number > 8 which would result in #ref! error. Can you give an example of what you are trying to look up e.g. $B8 and $B10 values and expected result?

Comment: So my $B8 is something like Conazoles (An item from the Assay Column) and the $B10 is Mobile_Phase_L (An Item from Mobile Phase Column). I need it to use both to narrow down into API-13 Conazoles Line C1(From the Instrument Line Column

Comment: On that criteria your query would appear to get row 19 on first match and row 20 on second match then try to lookup row 19 col 20 in instrument table. You need to either restructure your table or create a new key column for your specific lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods to produce a two-column-lookup. I use AGGREGATE to retrieve a matching row number. When using this with structured tables, you need to subtract the header row number from the row number retrieved in order to get an accurate result.

```
=INDEX(MP_Val_Table[instrument_line], AGGREGATE(15, 7, (ROW(MP_Val_Table[id])-ROW(MP_Val_Table[#Headers]))/((MP_Val_Table[assay]=$B$8)*(MP_Val_Table[mobile_phone]=$B$10)), ROW(1:1)))
```

Drag down for additional matches. Wrap with IFERROR to avoid displaying the #NUM! errors when you run out of matches to retrieve.

[image]

The Data, Advanced Filter method is another method of quickly determining single or multiple matches.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a multiple criteria match with an array formula that looks like this

```
=INDEX(MP_Val_Table[Instrument Line],MATCH(1,($B8 = MP_Val_Table[Assay])*($B10=MP_Val_Table[Mobile Phase]),0))
```

[image: Simplified example]

Because it is an array formula you need to press ctrl-shift-enter to evaluate it instead of just enter. This can be broken down into parts e.g.
$B8 = MP_Val_Table[Assay]  will return true or false
$B10 = MP_Val_Table[Mobile Phase]  will return true or false
Then the * of those results will be true or false, only the true result will match 1.

Because of the special handling needed for array formulas is is often easier to add a new column that concatenates the columns you wish to match on then do your match on that new column.

```
MATCH(concat($B8,$B10),MP_Val_Table[ConcatSearchColumn],0)
```